# Create a Boolean Column that checks for uid elsehwere in a Dataframe matching a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe:

| Case_no | Event_ID | Date | Type | Done_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | Response | Agent |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-01-03 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-01-10 | Response | Agent |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-01-02 | Email Sent | Customer |
| 2 | 6 | 2023-01-04 | Email Sent | Customer |

And I wanted to add two boolean columns that check for each case if an email has been sent in, has there been a response within 5 days on that case. There is no way to link emails and responses but just having it flag up that a response has been sent and whether or not it was in 5 days after is good enough for what I am doing as such:

| Case_no | Event_ID | Date | Type | Done_by | Response? | Response_Within_Five_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Email Sent | Customer | TRUE | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-02 | Response | Agent | nan | NAN |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-01-03 | Email Sent | Customer | TRUE | FALSE |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-01-10 | Response | Agent | NAN | NAN |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-01-02 | Email Sent | Customer | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | 6 | 2023-01-04 | Email Sent | Customer | FALSE | FALSE |

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Write a custom function and use `apply` on your column of interest.

Comment: Cheers! How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Don't know...what is the response column supposed to be based on? 1st and 3rd rows have `True` and the last two `False`, although the type and done_by are the same...

Comment: Response Column checks for a certain case_no, if a response has been recorded at all, we can see for Case no 2 there are two emails but no responses, but for case 1 there are responses on the emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for compare per groups if next value after `Email Sent` is `Response` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

shift = df.groupby('Case_no')[['Type','Date']].shift(-1)

m1 = df['Type'].eq('Email Sent')
m2 = shift['Type'].eq('Response')
m3 = shift['Date'].sub(df['Date']).dt.days.lt(5)

df['Response?'] = (m1 & m2).astype('boolean')
df['Response_Within_Five_Days'] = df['Response?'] & m3

df.loc[df['Type'].eq('Response'), ['Response?','Response_Within_Five_Days']] = np.nan
print (df)
   Case_no  Event_ID       Date        Type   Done_by  Response?  \
0        1         1 2023-01-01  Email Sent  Customer       True   
1        1         2 2023-01-02    Response     Agent       <NA>   
2        1         3 2023-01-03  Email Sent  Customer       True   
3        1         4 2023-01-10    Response     Agent       <NA>   
4        2         5 2023-01-02  Email Sent  Customer      False   
5        2         6 2023-01-04  Email Sent  Customer      False   

   Response_Within_Five_Days  
0                       True  
1                       <NA>  
2                      False  
3                       <NA>  
4                      False  
5                      False
```

EDIT: For check next rows after `Email Sent` use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    
    m = x['Type'].eq('Email Sent')
    for k, v in x.loc[m, 'Date'].items():
        s = x[~m].loc[k:, 'Date'].sub(v).dt.days
        x.loc[k, 'Response?'] = not s.empty
        x.loc[k, 'Response_Within_Five_Days'] = s.lt(5).any()

    return x

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df =  df.groupby('Case_no').apply(f)
print (df)
   Case_no  Event_ID       Date        Type   Done_by Response?  \
0        1         1 2023-01-01  Email Sent  Customer      True   
1        1         2 2023-01-02    Response     Agent       NaN   
2        1         3 2023-01-03  Email Sent  Customer      True   
3        1         4 2023-01-10    Response     Agent       NaN   
4        2         5 2023-01-02  Email Sent  Customer     False   
5        2         6 2023-01-04  Email Sent  Customer     False   

  Response_Within_Five_Days  
0                      True  
1                       NaN  
2                     False  
3                       NaN  
4                     False  
5                     False
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I am looking for, I want to compare it against all responses in the dataframe for that case, not just the next one, which, correct me if I'm wrong, is what this is looking at?

Comment: @brutusbombocloth - So how I know matching `Email Sent` to `Response` if not compare next row? Can you change data for your new requirement?

Comment: For the purpose of this exercise it does not matter if an email has a matching response, just that a response has been sent on that case within 5 days of an incoming email

Comment: @brutusbombocloth - Not understand, how is matching? Is possible one `Email Sent` to multiple `Response`s ?

Comment: Yes that is possible, the criteria just has to be that there is a response sent after the email and within 5 days

Comment: @brutusbombocloth - If one `Response` is in 5 days and another in 20 days per group `Case_no` need True for `Response_Within_Five_Days` ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't request this... I am just the man tasked with making it, I have already asked these baffling questions as well